# Which prepositions to use with computer trees?

Tags: prepositions, programming

Given a tree-like computational data structure, something where every entity (except for the root entity) has exactly one parent and may have any number of children (for example, the internal structure of an XML file). How do I say correctly: *You can click this button to insert an element* above / on top of / before / in front of / previous *the highlighted element, clicking the other button will insert it* below / under / after / behind / next *the selection.* Insertion here is about the same hierarchical level (not children).

Further question: What is the most common term for the entities of such a tree-like data structure? Elements? Nodes? Levels? Layers? Structures? I mean: Which word, if read out a context, is most likely to explain that it is part of a data tree? Like in a sentence as: *The function takes two numbers and a … and returns a string.*

Comment: Generally speaking, "node", "branch", "level", and "leaf" are used for describing trees.  "Element" is rarely used, and "structure" is incredibly vague and generic.  And I would find "layers" to be confusing in this context.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XML as far as I can tell and HTML DOM the word is "node". And the relationship between sibling nodes uses before/previous and after/next. So: "The function takes two numbers and a node and returns a string"; "insert an element before the highlighted element"; "click here to access the next child". Look up an XML parser and read the documentation and function names to have a clearer idea.

In my experience "node" is the most common term for tree-like computational data structures but I don't think it's such a fixed terminology that you can't pick other words if you prefer, and if it makes sense in your project.

Comment: Actually, in XML (or more precisely, in the XPath language) there are *preceding-sibling* and *following-sibling* nodes, and there are *preceding* and *following* nodes.

Comment: @michael.hor257k Fair enough. I'm basing my statements on the XML::Twig parser for Perl and the XML parser in Qt. Though checking on the latter I'm reminded that it refers to "nodes" as "elements" (though I think "element" in QXmlStreamReader might be more general than just nodes ? Anyway, it illustrates that there isn't a fixed convention on this).

Comment: At least with XML, there **is** a fixed convention - it is embodied in the official [XML](https://www.w3.org/TR/REC-xml) and [XPath](https://www.w3.org/TR/xpath) specification documents.